# Matt Ryall’s jQuery live filter - only return results that start with the string?

Tags: jquery

Can Matt Ryall’s jQuery live filter be modified to only show results that begin with the search text?

http://mattryall.net/blog/2008/07/jquery-filter-demo
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by adding a caret in front of the regular expression, it will enforce that the string starts with the inputted value.

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    $(".filtered:first li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp("^" + filter, "i")) < 0) { // ADDED CARET HERE
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
            count++;
        }
    });
    $("#filter-count").text(count);
});
```